# Lifetime of arena in long-running web server

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm working on a compiler pipeline and am not sure how to properly model ownership of ASTs with arenas.

I have types inside the AST represented as references into arenas (quite like `rustc`'s own [`TyCtxt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nightly-rustc/rustc_middle/ty/struct.TyCtxt.html)), using `typed_arena`. As a dummy example (but happy to provide more details):

```rust
use typed_arena::Arena;

enum Ty<'ty> {
  Int,
  List(&'ty Ty<'ty>),
}

enum Expr<'ty> {
  Literal(isize),
  List(Vec<Expr<'ty>>),
  TypeAnnotated(Expr<'ty>, &'ty Ty<'ty>)
}

fn parse_and_type_check<'ty>(input: String, ty_arena: &'ty Arena<Ty<'ty>>) -> Expr<'ty> {
  todo!()
}
```

This works fine for running the compile pipeline by itself, but now I'd like to use this in a language server, where I want `Expr<'ty>` to live for as long as needed:

```rust
struct LanguageServerState<'ty> {
  latest_program: Option<(Arena<'ty>, Expr<'ty>)>,
}

fn main() {


  let mut state = LanguageServerState { latest_program: None };

  // in reality, this is accepting connections and selecting receiving messages from an LSP client
  loop {
     // ...on a new program
     let new_program = "[1, [2, 3]]".to_owned();
     let fresh_arena = Arena::new();
     let new_program = parse_and_type_check(new_program, &fresh_arena);
     state = LanguageServerState { latest_program: Some((fresh_arena, new_program)) };

     // ...on some LSP request I may need to do something using `latest_program`

  }
}
```

It makes sense that this won't pass the borrow checker - as written the code would allow me to drop the `Arena` in `LanguageServerState` without dropping `Expr<'ty>`, which would leave dangling pointers.

I'm just not sure: what is the right way to model the `LanguageServerState` in a situation like this? I really need to be able to reclaim memory from the arena when the program itself is dropped, but I need the whole program + arena to live until the net version of the program has been parsed and type checked.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have hard times. You're trying to create a [self-referential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32300132/why-cant-i-store-a-value-and-a-reference-to-that-value-in-the-same-struct) struct.

The easiest way will probably be to use one of the self-referential crates readily available.

For example, with [`yoke`](https://docs.rs/yoke) (note I switched the typed arena to an [untyped arena](https://docs.rs/bumpalo), since `yoke` has problems with the lifetime in the arena. This can lead to problems if there you allocate types that need to be dropped. The advantage is you can also allocate `Expr`s there, though):

```rust
use bumpalo::Bump;

#[derive(yoke::Yokeable)]
enum Ty<'ty> {
    Int,
    List(&'ty [Ty<'ty>]),
}

#[derive(yoke::Yokeable)]
enum Expr<'ty> {
    Literal(isize),
    List(Vec<Expr<'ty>>),
    TypeAnnotated(Box<Expr<'ty>>, &'ty Ty<'ty>),
}

fn parse_and_type_check<'ty>(input: String, ty_arena: &'ty Bump) -> Expr<'ty> {
    todo!()
}

struct LanguageServerState {
    latest_program: Option<yoke::Yoke<Expr<'static>, Box<Bump>>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = LanguageServerState {
        latest_program: None,
    };

    // in reality, this is accepting connections and selecting receiving messages from an LSP client
    loop {
        // ...on a new program
        let new_program = "[1, [2, 3]]".to_owned();
        let fresh_arena = Bump::new();
        state = LanguageServerState {
            latest_program: Some(yoke::Yoke::attach_to_cart(
                Box::new(fresh_arena),
                |fresh_arena| parse_and_type_check(new_program, fresh_arena),
            )),
        };

        // ...on some LSP request I may need to do something using `latest_program`
    }
}
```